# При копировании текста из cmd в буфере оказыватюся символы ANSI escape code

Tags: windows, cmd, dll, windows-7, clipboard

ОС Windows 7 64

Затронуты:
cmd
ConEmu64

Для того чтобы получить цветной вывод в консоль, я установил

ANSICON ansi189 с сайта

http://adoxa.altervista.org/ansicon/index.html

и также clink
https://mridgers.github.io/clink/

Настроить цветной вывод не получилось.

После  удаления  ansi189 и clink при копировании текста из cmd или ConEmu в буфере обмена  оказыватюся символы ANSI escape code .

Пример:
Как должно быть:

```
c:\windows\syswow64\
```

Как сейчас:

```
[37m[40mregsvr32 c:\windows\syswow64\A[m
```

Откат системы не помог, предполагаю, что это связано с тем, что что-то не удалено до конца
( возможно, нужно заменить какой-нибудь DLL  ).

К сожалению, четкого понимания куда копать у меня нет. В google, найти решение не получилось.

Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Comment: А в этих ветвях точно следов не осталось? **HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun**

**HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun**